# How do I pass a list of integers to an MVC action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have an action that depends on a list of integers.  My first instinct was to simply declare the action with a List.

I tried declaring the action in the controller as:

```
public ActionResult EditMultiple(List<int> ids)
```

and in my View call like so:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("EditMultiple", "EditMultiple", new { ids = new List<int> {2, 2, 2} })%>
```

Although it compiles the List is empty when I put a breakpoint in the action.  Anybody know why or have an alternate approach?

**Adding more detail about the scenario:**

I'm trying to "Edit" multiple entities at the same time.  I'm already at the point where I have an application that allows me to create/edit/view information about books in a library.  I have a partial view that allows the user to edit information about a single book and save it to the database.

Now I'd like to create a View which allows the user to edit the information about multiple books with a single submit button.  I've created an action EditMultiple which just renders the partial for each book (my model for this view is List) and adds the submit button afterwards.

Comment: what are you posting to the action?

Comment: In this case my example above is somewhat close to my real scenario.  This is the GET not the POST.  I'll update the description with some more info about the real scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The default model binder can bind "ids" to any ICollection. But you have to submit multiple parameters with the same name. That eliminates using the helper method "ActionLink". You can use url helper Action and append the ids to the link like so:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("CreateMultiple")%>?ids=2&ids=1&ids=3">Test link</a>
```

[Here's the link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) from Haack's block.

Comment: That works thanks.  Sad that I can't use the Html helper but the hardcoded values are just for prototyping so it does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think

```
new List<int> {2, 2, 2}
```

gets properly converted into an POST that is bindable, you want to send

```
Ids=1&Ids=2&Ids=3
```

a comma separate list may also work, im not sure, i don't use the crappy default modelbinder.

Why are you doing that anyway? I hope thats pseudocode for something else...

Comment: more details added to the question.  of course I'm not actually editing books but for purposes of this discussion that's good enough.  If you can think of a better way to edit multiple books than creating an Action for EditMultiple which renders the Partial for each model in a list than please I'm all ears.  This is my first real MVC app so I'm still learning the framework and design patterns.

Comment: Thus, note to future people who are trying to figure out, as I was, how to submit to an MVC action where the client was also submitting programmatically (via FormUrlEncodedContent): that means just loop through and add the same key to the list of KVPs you're creating the FormUrlEncodedContent from, multiple times, with different values (it is after all just a List<KeyValuePair>, not a proper Dictionary, so that's allowed (and worked!)