# Passing a collection of parameters to an Action in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. In this application, I need to query based upon a selected list of values. My question is, is there a way to pass a List as a parameter to a view in asp.net mvc? For instance, ideally, I would like to use the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult CustomerOrderStatus(List<int> orderIDs)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

I'm not sure how to route the mapping in my controller. Is this approach possible?

Comment: Handy tip: Since it's MVC 3, you can replace [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
 with [HttpGet]. If you want to, that is.

Comment: Do you intend to access this method via an ajax call or form submittal or something else?

Answer (score 1):

well, you could use a little Url.helper along the lines of:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string ListToAction (this UrlHelper helper, string listName, int[] values)
    {
        string finalOutput =  values.Aggregate("?", (current, value) => 
                                current + string.Format("{0}={1}&", listName, value));
        return finalOutput.Substring(0, finalOutput.LastIndexOf("&"));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CustomerOrderStatus")@Url.ListToAction("orderIDs", new int[]{1,2,6,9})">Test link</a>
```

just a wild thought :)

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208582/how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-integers-to-an-mvc-action) is a possible solution

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("CustomerOrderStatus")%>?ids=2&ids=1&ids=3">Test link</a>
```